# Yii2 debug mysql queries or mysql_error equivalent

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii2

I have a model helper called `ValuesHelper` in common/models with the following code snippet:

```
 <?php
    namespace common\models;
    class ValueHelpers
    {
      /**
         * return the value of status by the its name string
         * example: 'Active'
         * @param string $status_name
         */
        public static function getStatusValue($sta8tus_name)
        {
            $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM status WHERE status_name=:status_name";      
            $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
            $command->bindValue(':status_name', $status_name);  
// the issue in the next line   
            $result = $command->queryOne() or die($connection->getFirstError()."error");
            return $result['id'];
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to implement like `mysql_error()` in `or die()` clause. I tried `or die ($command->getFirstError())` but it failed too. By the way, on purpose, I set wrong parameter name `$sta8tus` to format an environment for creating the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not look at the logs instead of putting a die there?

Also take a look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryOne()-detail
If the command has a problem then it throws an exception. You have to catch that exception and use it, that is the best practice.

So do a

```
try {
    $result = $command->queryOne();
} catch (yii\db\Exception $e) {
    do your stuff here
}
```